# Listview to another activity with image views?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview inside a fragment class. When a listview item is clicked another activity is opened. The xml file of that activity has 2 imageviews inside a scroll view. The images change with respect to every listview item clicked. No matter which listview item i click on it shows the same image view. In my case it shows the R.drawable.geet94 no mater which listview item i click.

```
public class urdufrag1 extends Fragment {

    public urdufrag1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    private static final String TAG = "urdufrag1";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
    main_content, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.geetfrag_urdu, main_content, false);



         final int[] menuImage = {R.drawable.tgeet94, 
         R.drawable.tgeet95,R.drawable.tgeet96,R.drawable.tgeet97};
        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.GeetListU);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PackageG.class);
                //intent.putExtra("GeetType", 
        listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                //intent.putExtra("GeetType", Integer.toString(position));
                intent.putExtra("position", Integer.toString(position));
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        AdapterGeetUrdu adapter = new AdapterGeetUrdu(getContext(), menuImage);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment



        return view;
    }
}
```

Second Activity

```
public class PackageG extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView img1, img2;
    PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_package_g);

        img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
        img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
        mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(img1);
        mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(img2);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        if(intent != null){
            Integer position = intent.getExtras().getInt("position");

            switch (position){

                case 0: img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.geet94);
                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.geet94_1);
                    break;
                case 1: img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.geet95);
                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.geet95_1);
                    break;
                case 2: img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.geet96);
                        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.geet96_1);
                    break;

                default:
                    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.carol);
                    img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.carol);
                    break;

            }

        }

        mAttacher.update();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> intent.putExtra("position", Integer.toString(position));

This is where you made mistake.

Change this to, and will solve your problem.

```
intent.putExtra("position", position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your activity you are expecting an integer but you are passing string position from listview. Change the click listener as per the below code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PackageG.class);    
      intent.putExtra("position", position);
      startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```